# ubuntu 12.04 frozen

Tags: 12.04

i installed ubuntu 12.04. when i went to update manager, it showed over 300 updates. when i hit updates, it started to with waiting and that small circle going round and round. I waited 1 hour and then the computer shut down still waiting. when I started the computer the arrow disapearred, My whole computer is practically frozen. When I try to shut down, it goes back to enter password position

Answer (score 1):

For huge updates, fall back to the terminal, type the following in to a terminal of your choice, for the most luck, try tty1-tty6 (press ctrl+alt+F1). Login if in a tty, then do the following.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This SHOULD work, and will allow you to see possible error when downloading/updating the system. Post those errors here for more help if this does not work.

EDIT - FYI to get back to your GUI, go ctrl+alt+f7